# Cursor in textfield doesn't always show up

Tags: android, react-native

In my react native(0.48) android app, I have a textfield for searching. It has autofocus property enabled. But the cursor doesn't always show up in the textField, thought the keyboard is persistent and always comes up. This is a random issue. I can get my cursor back by clicking on Textfield again.

Comment: please show your manifest file or check android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Comment: There is no tag for windowSoftInputMode in manifest.